# How to create a webservice SOAP with Grails 4.0.1

Tags: grails, soap

Dear friends I need some good reference to understand how to create a SOAP webservice with Grails 4.0.1. I created a library of services and I need to provide some methods as endpoints to be consumed by other applications.
I do not know which plugin would be most suitable for use with version 4.